# Does you know how the CCK Private Fields module works? Any API?

Tags: entities, users

Do you know how the CCK Private Fields module works?
What I'm interested in is having a user who can switch all their content profile fields to private.

Is there an API that I can call to switch all the user's content profile fields to private?
Is there any better way to have a user opt-out and become basically an invisible user?
The definition I'm getting for opt-out is to never display the user in any search, browse or page.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [description page](http://drupal.org/project/cck_private_fields) of this module, it seems that user can do what you want:

> Overview:
>
> This module allows users to mark administrator selected CCK fields as
>   Public (visible to everyone), Hidden (visible to node author, hidden
>   from everyone else) or Private (visible to node author and "friends";
>   see requirements section below).

Regarding the option to "disappear" a user, I'm not really sure as there's a lot of place where a user can appear, however if you give this user a certain role, you can customize your views to exclude users with this role.